# links in d3.js forced directed graph

Tags: javascript, svg, append, hyperlink, d3.js

In [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/1153292), how can I make the text of each node to be a clickable link?

I tried something similar to this code, but the values were not clickable:

```
var links = text.append("a").attr("xlink:href", "http://www.google.com/");

// A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
links.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .attr("class", "shadow")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

 links.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

EDIT / SOLUTION: turns out the css had this attriubte: pointer-events: none;
I had to delete it and then use as Elijah suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use links, drop it and append directly to your text `<g>` and it should work.

```
text.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", 8)
        .attr("y", ".31em")
        .attr("class", "shadow")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .on("click", function() {yourFunction(yourVar)})
        .on("mouseover", function() {yourFunction2(yourVar)})
        .on("mouseout", function() {yourFunction3(yourVar)})
;
```

Also, if you want to pass the bound data, you'd do that like this:

```
.on("click", function(d) {yourFunction(d.yourVar)}
```

Whereas if you want to pass the actual d object, you can do it like this:

```
.on("click", yourFunction}
```

In which case yourFunction(d,i) can then reference d.whatever from your bound data.

Comment: thanks but I cannot get it to work. Here is the code I use https://gist.github.com/3784067 and here is the live page http://bl.ocks.org/3784067

Comment: Wait, Mike's original gist never attached an <a> element, it attaches a <g> element. If you maintain that pattern and don't try to use the a href pattern, then it should work. I'll adjust my answer, let me know if that works.

Comment: still does not work. I just added 2 lines of event attachment to the original code. gist/demo: https://gist.github.com/3785177 http://bl.ocks.org/3785177